# Extract email addresses from json output in Elasticsearch with Regex

Tags: python, json, regex, elasticsearch

I have thousands of Telegram messages stored in my Elasticsearch index. I need to extract the email addresses that have been mentioned by users on Telegram. email addresses are within [_source][text] and are posted within posts, so I need to use REGEX:

```
([\s]{0,10}[\w.]{1,63}@[\w.]{1,63}[\s]{0,10})
```

to do the following:

- a) extract the email address from each message;
- b) create a new Maltego entity

I am trying this code (I am totally new to Python/to coding!), but it does not work:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    from MaltegoTransform import *
    import json
    import os
    import re


    m = MaltegoTransform()

    indexname = sys.argv[1]

    es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')

    res = es.search(index=indexname, size=1000, body={"query": {"match": 
    {"entities.type": "email"}}})

    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:

     def get_emails(data=""):

      addresses = re.findall(r'[\s]{0,10}[\w.]{1,63}@[\w.]{1,63}[\s]{0,10}', data)
      print addresses #does not print anything#

     m.addEntity('maltego.EmailAddress', ''.join(WHAT?))

    m.returnOutput()
```

**This is a sample of my json output:**

```
    {
    took: 5,
    timed_out: false,
    _shards: {
    total: 1,
    successful: 1,
    skipped: 0,
    failed: 0
    },
    hits: {
    total: 43,
    max_score: 7.588423,
    hits: [
    {
    _index: "MY_INDEX",
    _type: "items",
    _id: "CHANNEL ID",
    _score: 7.588423,
    _source: {
    id: 2411,
    audio: { },
    author_signature: null,
    caption: null,
    channel_chat_created: null,
    chat: {},
    command: null,
    service: null,
    sticker: { },
    supergroup_chat_created: null,
    text: HERE'S THE TEXT CONTAINING EMAIL ADDRESS.
```

The text I need to search into for emails is therefore nested  in [_source][text]. I need to extract only the email address (by regex) withi it, and be able to print it and use it in a "function", in order to create a graph entity in Maltego. The function looks like this:

```
m.addEntity('maltego.EmailAddress', ''.join(THE EMAIL ENTITY EXTRACTED WITH REGEX)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] the question to give some samples of the data your are working with and what the desired output would be?

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I added some info. Hope it's got enough info now. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Your main question is really, "how can I extract the email address from this text"? The rest of the information is not really needed. But we would need to see examples of the text that contains the email. Finding email addresses in text is not particularly easy.

Comment: Hi Ron, glad to see that you've managed to solve your own problem. Instead of editing your question to include the working code, could you please write your solution as an answer to your question using the field below, and then rollback your question to the last revision? That way, if anyone else comes along in the future and has the same problem, they will be easily able to tell if this question is similar to theirs, and will be able to read the solution below. Thanks!

Comment: of course Angus. I will asap.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I have suggested an edit to your question so that the last revision will be shown, which shows the non-working code - that way, we'll have a proper question-answer pair that may be helpful to future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the email addresses will depend on what your library requires. The correct approach could be to use `addEntity()` once for each email address, or it might be to add all addresses to a single call.

To add each email address using `addEntity()` use:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
res = es.search(index=indexname, size=1000, body={"query": {"match": {"entities.type": "email"}}})
response = json.dumps(res)
data = json.loads(response)

fulltext = []

for row in data['hits']['hits']:
    fulltext.append(row['_source']['text'].encode('utf8'))

for text in fulltext:
    emails = re.findall("[\s]{0,10}([\w.]{1,63}@[\w.]{1,63})[\s]{0,10}", text)

    for email in set(emails):
        m.addEntity('maltego.EmailAddress', email)

m.returnOutput()
```

Using `''.join(email)` as you have seen will create a single string with no delimiters between email addresses. To add all email addresses with a `,` separating them:

```
emails = re.findall("[\s]{0,10}([\w.]{1,63}@[\w.]{1,63})[\s]{0,10}", text)
m.addEntity('maltego.EmailAddress', ','.join(emails))
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. This solves the problem with emails. But not with Urls (don't understand why they are still printed together in the same entity). Furthermore, I need to find a solution to exclude whitespaces, because for example i got two entities on the graph as the same email has been captured with and without a whitespace before the address.

Comment: To remove the whitespace from the ends, you can just move the `(` and `)` inward in the regular expression. A `set()` could be used to remove duplicate email addresses.

Comment: Update: i changed the email regex, which was bad, and now it's ok. Stilli figuring how to get the job done with urls.

Comment: Perhaps best as a separate question. Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons next to the answer to select it as the accepted solution when you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to get the code working, like this:

```
    es = Elasticsearch()

   res = es.search(index=indexname, size=1000, body={"query": {"match": 
    {"entities.type": "email"}}})
    response = json.dumps(res)
    data = json.loads(response)

   fulltext = []

    for row in data['hits']['hits']:
     fulltext.append(row['_source']['text'].encode('utf8'))

    for text in fulltext:

     email = re.findall("([\s]{0,10}[\w.]{1,63}@[\w.]{1,63}[\s]{0,10})", text)

     m.addEntity('maltego.EmailAddress', ''.join(email))

    m.returnOutput()
```

The problem with this code is that if multiple email addresses are in the same post, i get the results like email1@domain.comemail2@domain.com.

Ho can I split the two addresses in order to add each one to my Maltego graph with .join(email)?

Comment: If you used `','.join(email)` it would add a comma between them. If you want separate entities, you'd need a loop.

Comment: I have tried a loop before, but it renders only one single entity and not all the entities that match the regex.
Could you suggest a solution?